# Mysql: optimizing indexes

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I installed MySQL Tuner and this was the result of the report:

- Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
- Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes

So, i enabled the slow query log and it reported these kind of queries:

> SELECT
>   u.PIN,u.name,u.lastname,u.id_country,t1.id_user_list,COUNT(t2.id_user_list)
>   AS q1 FROM contact AS t1, contact AS
>   t2, user AS u WHERE t1.id_user=N AND
>   t2.id_user = t1.id_user_list AND
>   u.id_user = t1.id_user_list GROUP BY
>   t1.id_user_list ORDER BY name,lastname

And...

> SELECT * FROM user WHERE city LIKE 'S'
>   AND gender = N AND flg_pic = N AND
>   flg_hidden = N AND flg_ban = N AND
>   id_user != N ORDER BY id_user DESC
>   LIMIT N,N

I just need some help regarding the optimization of my tables, which are:

1. **contact**

   - id_contact (int / primary index)
   - id_user (int / index)
   - id_user_list (int / index)
2. **user**

   - id_user (int / primary index)
   - name (varchar)
   - lastname (varchar)
   - PIN (varchar)
   - id_country (int)
   - city (varchar)
   - gender (1 or 2)
   - flg_pic (1 or 0)
   - flg_hidden (1 or 0)
   - flg_ban (1 or 0)

Should i index all varchars that are used in the queries (WHERE and ORDER) as well? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should run explain analyze to get a better idea of what the most expensive parts of your query are, and index or optimize around those fields.

eg:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM user WHERE city LIKE 'S' AND gender = N AND flg_pic = N AND flg_hidden = N AND flg_ban = N AND id_user != N ORDER BY id_user DESC LIMIT N,N
```

and you should prioritize those slow queries that run the most often and the most slowly

Comment: I think you just want `EXPLAIN`, not `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.